# Magento - price rule "buy 2 for price X"

Tags: magento, rule, price

How can make the following rule.

Product: T.Shirts comes in 5 colours and in 5 sizes. It is set up as a configurable product.

Buy one for 120.-
Buy any 2 for 200.-

With buying 2 I mean not just buying 2 in color red, and size Large. It should also work when you buy 1 red/large, 1 blue/small etc.

Is there a way to set it up without buying an extension? I work on a Magento 1.9.2.3

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn´t aware of that. Thanks for the link to the correct place to ask the question.

Answer (score 0):

First go to admin->manage product and open any product for that you want to set this functionality.

Magento called "Tier price" to this functionality.

after open product there is price tab on left side go to it.

There is Tire price section so click on "add Tier" and fill all data.

you set Tier price.

Done.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. What you are describing is valid only if the customer chooses to buy 2 or more pieces of the same color and of the same size. This is not what I was asking for.